# asp.net chart. Column not found error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, charts

I am trying to display asp.net chart.
i have written following code

```
public SqlDataAdapter da;
DataSet ds1;
public DataSet SelectDayWiseEnquiriesForCChart()
{
    int orgid;
    orgid = ((int)Session["orgid"]);
    DbConnect objdbc = new DbConnect();
    SqlConnection con = objdbc.openConnection();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT EnquiryOwner,Count(uid) from EnquiryMaster WHERE orgid='" + orgid + "' and ( DAY(date) = DAY(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) ) group by EnquiryOwner", con);
    ds1 = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds1);
    return ds1;
}

protected void FillChartControl()
{
    Chart1.DataSource = SelectDayWiseEnquiriesForCChart();

    Chart1.DataBind();
}
       <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
            <series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="EnquiryOwner" YValueMembers="uid">
                </asp:Series>
            </series>
            <chartareas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </chartareas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

I am getting an error column with name uid not found
i am not able to understand why am i getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an alias for your count() expression in your query.

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT EnquiryOwner,Count(uid) as uid from EnquiryMaster WHERE ....
```

Then you can use that name in `YValueMembers="uid"`

Taken from MSDN:

> ...You can access the return result using the ordinal position, 0, as the result name. To access the return result by column name, the query must include an AS  clause to provide a column name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280492%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

Comment: thanks that error is gone but my chart control is not displayed on web page when i run my application